# How to use the asset pipeline in liquid

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, liquid

I want to use the asset pipeline `icw Liquid`, but how can I create the `asset_path` from within Liquid. I Know Shopify has [asset_url](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/filters/asset-url/) so i created a custom `Liquid::Filter`

But when I create a `Liquid::Filter` to port the `ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper.asset_path`, it doesn't seem to find the asset. I'm probably in the wrong context?

So how does Shopify do that? :)

Answer (score 1):

Shopify's asset_url tag doesn't give you the asset url of of their rails app assets, it gives you the asset url of the asset within your shop itself (or from the theme, which is within your shop). Take a look at https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/master/performance/shopify/shop_filter.rb.

If you need to make the asset_url tag access assets from within your app itself then you can use something like ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(filename) within your asset_url tag implementation.

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for replying. I've user the ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path and created an tag. But somehow is doesn't seem to find the asset. It simple returns the file without the asset path. Maybe the tag is in a different content then the Tag/Filter function?

But when I use the helper function from outside that tag, so in the controller scope itself, it works as excepted..